# c# search concatenated column using textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

How can I search concatenated columns? I know how to do a single column search but what I want is to search concatenated column.. Please help me

```
public void searchenrolee()
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string value = "Fullname";

            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                        @"Select EEid, CONCAT(Fname,' ', Mname,' ', Lname) AS Fullname, DateRegistered
                        from studenttbl
                        where {0} like @searchKey AND year(DateRegistered) = '" + cbStudYear.selectedValue.ToString() + "' AND Enrollingto = '" + cbSLGrade.selectedValue.ToString() + "' order by EEid desc", value);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchKey", '%' + tbsearchEnrolee.Text.ToString() + '%');
            MySqlDataAdapter kuhain = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dgvStudentList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    private void tbsearchEnrolee_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchenrolee();
    }
```

Comment: you are still searching just one column in db i.e. `value`. Please clarify more on what you are asking.

Comment: I have 3 columns(Fname, Mname and Lname). If I search JAMES for example, if the program find JAMES in any column(Fname, Mname or Lname) it will display in the datagridview.

Comment: You would have to do the `CONCAT` again in the `WHERE` clause. If MySql operates the same as MSSQL, the select clause is actually the last part to execute and `fullname` is not evaluated yet in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Crowcoder How? I tried (where CONCAT(Fname,' ', Mname,' ', Lname) = '{0} like @searchKey') its not working

Comment: It should be like: `.. WHERE CONCAT(Fname,' ', Mname,' ', Lname) LIKE @searchKey`

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder It's working!.Godbless you

Comment: I didn't add an answer because I wasn't totally sure about MySql (I'm a MSSQL user) but you should probably add your own solution as an answer and accept it so people don't waste time reading your question and the comments when the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

answer by Crowcoder

```
public void searchenrolee()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        string value = "Fullname";

        cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                    @"Select EEid, CONCAT(Fname,' ', Mname,' ', Lname) AS Fullname, DateRegistered
                    from studenttbl
                    where CONCAT(Fname,' ', Mname,' ', Lname) like @searchKey AND year(DateRegistered) = '" + cbStudYear.selectedValue.ToString() + "' AND Enrollingto = '" + cbSLGrade.selectedValue.ToString() + "' order by EEid desc", value);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchKey", '%' + tbsearchEnrolee.Text.ToString() + '%');
        MySqlDataAdapter kuhain = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        dgvStudentList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}

private void tbsearchEnrolee_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchenrolee();
}
```

Comment: Although it won't break, better to remove `String.Format` as it's useless now.